# How to change to the current date in the form for twitter-bootstrap

Tags: date, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to change the date to current date in the form for twitter bootstrap. I would like it to change it automatically without me changing it manually.

Code:

```
<label>Created:</label>
<input type="text" value="11/06/2012" id="datepicker"/>
<br/><br/>
```

I would like the value "06/11/2012" to be automatically changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use JavaScript:

```
var date = new Date();
document.getElementById('datepicker').value = date.getDate() + '/' + date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
```